# unable to hook to a ui view inside interface

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, interface, theos

I am using THEOS, and I know how to hook to methods and override and stuff. But now what I want to do is, I want to access the UI views that are declared within (@interface).

Here is the header file I am referring to:

```
@class NSString, UILabel, UINavigationBar, UISwitch;

__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationBarDelegate, UIBarPositioningDelegate>
{
UINavigationBar *navBar;
UISwitch *alertSwitch;
UISwitch *lightSwitch;
UISwitch *lockSwitch;
UISwitch *infoSwitch;
UILabel *alertLabel;
UILabel *lightLabel;
UILabel *lockLabel;
UILabel *showInfoLabel;
UILabel *infoLabel;
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) UILabel *infoLabel; // @synthesize infoLabel;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UILabel *showInfoLabel; // @synthesize showInfoLabel;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UILabel *lockLabel; // @synthesize lockLabel;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UILabel *lightLabel; // @synthesize lightLabel;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UILabel *alertLabel; // @synthesize alertLabel;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UISwitch *infoSwitch; // @synthesize infoSwitch;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UISwitch *lockSwitch; // @synthesize lockSwitch;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UISwitch *lightSwitch; // @synthesize lightSwitch;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UISwitch *alertSwitch; // @synthesize alertSwitch;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UINavigationBar *navBar; // @synthesize navBar;
- (void).cxx_destruct;
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning;
- (void)dismissSettingsViewController;
- (long long)preferredStatusBarStyle;
- (void)showDevInfo;
- (void)infoSwitchSwitched;
- (void)lockSwitchSwitched;
- (void)lightSwitchSwitched;
- (void)alertSwitchSwitched;
- (void)viewDidLoad;
- (long long)positionForBar:(id)arg1;

// Remaining properties
@property(readonly, copy) NSString *debugDescription;
@property(readonly, copy) NSString *description;
@property(readonly) unsigned long long hash;
@property(readonly) Class superclass;

@end
```

I want to access the UI views under @interface (Ex: UISwitch *alertSwitch;).

How can I access it? Please help I am trying to figure it out since three days :(. Any help or suggestion is very very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help

```
%hook SettingsViewController
-(void) WhereEverYouWantToRunYourCode {

      self.alertSwitch = ....

    }

    %end
```